# Flutter - Firebase Firestore operation is not working

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am having a problem. First of all my code:

```
FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

//...

final userCredential = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
  email: _emailController.text,
  password: _passwordController.text,
);
print(userCredential.user?.uid); // mdaAcc1rXTe1s7VeWR7zcu6t4XD2
_firestore.collection("Users").doc(userCredential.user?.uid).set({
  "ID": userCredential.user?.uid,
  "Email": _emailController.text,
  "Phone": _phoneController.text,
  "Name": _nameController.text,
  "Surname": _surnameController.text,
  "Photo": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/teen-software-stock-tracking.appspot.com/o/default.jpg?alt=media&token=0eec2e1f-2ccf-4bda-8664-3d3f018621b3",
  "Level": 0,
  "ProductRight": 10,
  "AddedProduct": 0,
  "AccountCreate": FullDate.toString(),
});
```

The Firebase Auth process is running and the user's account is opened, but the Firestore process is not. The document does not open.

Why could this be? How can I solve it? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: I am not getting any errors. @Josteve

Comment: Have you checked the firestore rules?

Comment: Yes. There is no problem with the rules. Also I was able to create Document before. The code is out of the blue.

Comment: You might want to check if anything was changed from when you started this issue, also check for any connectivity issues,or any authentication warnings or errors you see from when this started occuring.

Comment: @Vaidehi Jamankar I am not getting any errors.

Comment: As suggested earlier, any changes made from when you have started seeing this issue.Also provide any screenshot if possible with more details of the configurations,removing any confidential infromation from that.